# Issue with the instantiation of the object _

Tags: underscore.js

I put underscore.js (downloaded from jashkenas' GitHub) and linked it with my html via the src attribute of . Still, after loading the HTML, and going to console mode, if I type _ and then give a . (dot), the list of methods and inner objects don't come up. Even if I use it with _.method  name, errors happen at each invocation. This has happened with the main .JS file, with the min .JS file, with the esm and umd files... Basically I am thoroughly confused as to when is it supposed to work.
Is there a browser version dependency, though I have failed using it even on the latest Chrome and Mozilla?

I am new to JS... please help. The documentation is not helping, trust me!

Comment: If you just open de dev console at underscorejs.org, can you use `_` as expected? If yes, the problem is in your code (please share it). If not, then the problem is in your browser (or your expectations). Put three backticks on a line (and nothing else) to switch to code display mode, then your code, then another three backticks to switch back to text mode.